# Omnicontacts redirect_uri: facebook, hotmail, yahoo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omnicontacts-gem

I am using the [omnicontacts gem](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts) so that users can invite their contacts on my website. I have set it up successfully for Google.

I have setup an omnicontacts controller with the contacts_callback method as suggested by the gem's readme.

and a route: `get "/contacts/:importer/callback" => "omnicontacts#contacts_callback"`

At the initializer of omnicontacts.rb I have the followings:

```
require "omnicontacts"

Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do

importer :gmail, "hidden-client-key", "hidden-secret-key", {redirect_path: "/contacts/gmail/callback"}
importer :facebook, "hidden-client-key", "hidden-secret-key", {:redirect_path => "/contacts/facebook/callback" }
importer :hotmail, "hidden-client-key", "hidden-secret-key", {redirect_path: "/contacts/hotmail/callback"}
end
```

The last two (facebook and hotmail) according to the gem's readme file do not need a redirect_path but just in case I tested both with it or not and I still get an error that the redirect_uri is invalid. As I was searching for a solution I found a place that the :redirect_path was instead :callback_path and tried that as well but no luck.

On the Microsoft app (for hotmail) I was getting a longer description on the error which was:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not
>   valid. The expected value is
>   'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches
>   the redirect URI registered for this client application.

As a result I went on and registered a redirect URI for this client application. The URI was http://example.com/contacts/hotmail/callback which matches the callback path.

Still, getting the same error. Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like you miss to pass you domain details from where you like to access your application please see in image and try to add you domain and try again..

same you need to do it for hotmail app

[image]